# How to add a watermark to all images in a folder using ImageMagik

Tags: imagemagick, watermark

I have been trying to find a way of watermarking all .jpg files in a given folder using ImageMagik directly from the terminal. I have searched a lot and I found the following:

```
composite -compose atop -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 wm.png *.jpg
```

What I want to achieve is to add the watermark(wm.png) right under the bottom-right corner of each image and save the file under the same name. All images are different width but none is wider than 800px. So my watermark image is 800px wide. I want the watermark to be put right under the image, not over it and in the same time being cut to fit the size of the .jpg image.

The problem with the command above is that it s always outputting the following error:

```
composite: unable to open image `'tm.png'': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2480.
composite: missing an image filename `10.jpg' @ composite.c/CompositeImageCommand/1593.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in *.jpg
do
    composite -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 wm.png  "$i" "wm_$i"
done
```

Comment: I am afraid that I am still getting the same error when using the above syntax.

Comment: Do you have a `tm.png` in current directory? These is no reason to have this error message.

Comment: It did work now. The watermark file was named wm, not tm. Now I am trying to make the wm image to get applied right after the end of the original image, at the bottom. Any ideas on the right coordinates?

Comment: Thank you. I used the -splice option and everything works just as wanted.